# How to change DSLD compile classpath in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, dsld

I'd like to do some import of my own classes for use inside DSLD script, but DSLD compilation does not seem to use project's classpath - import statements break the compilation, and Class.forName throws class not found exception.
Is there a way to put custom jars on DSLD classpath, so I can use my own classes inside conribution blocks?
I am using Eclipse 3.7 and latest groovy plugin (2.6.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass a string with the fully qualified class name and as long as its on the projects classpath where the DSLD is being evaluated then it will work.  This is described here [groovy-eclipse DSLDs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/DSL+Descriptors+for+Groovy-Eclipse#DSLDescriptorsforGroovy-Eclipse-Otherpointcuts)

> Some subtleties about java.lang.Class references
>
> Even though the DSLD script is being edited in the context of your
>   project, the script is actually loaded by Groovy-Eclipse. And so, the
>   runtime classpath of the script corresponds to Groovy-Eclipse's
>   classpath, rather than the classpath of your project.
>
> Consequently, you cannot reference class objects for types defined in
>   your project. However, you can reference class objects that are
>   available to Groovy-Eclipse. This might be confusing since the
>   compiler will not show compile errors when types defined in your
>   project are referenced as class objects, but it will show compile
>   errors when Groovy-Eclipse types are referenced. This is because the
>   Groovy-Eclipse compiler works off of the project's classpath. It is
>   not yet aware that DSLD files will be run with a different classpath.
>
> More specifically:
>
> Instead of referencing the class MyLocalType directly, you can
>   reference it as a String "com.mycompany.MyLocalType" Standard JDK,
>   GDK, and all types defined in groovy-all are available directly in
>   your DSLD and will show compile errors. It is possible to reference
>   types in packages beginning with org.eclipse.jdt. and
>   org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse. if all references are fully qualified.
>   However, this is not recommended unless you really know what you are
>   doing.

Comment: The question was about using custom classing in DSLD scripts, not just referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the DSLD stuff, but it [looks](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+2.5.1+New+and+Noteworthy?print=1#Groovy-Eclipse251NewandNoteworthy-GroovyDSLSupportclasspathcontainer) like Groovy might have it's own means of doing that.

Comment: This one is to share global DSLDs among your projects, and it is only meant for DSLD files. What I need is a way to hook even earlier  into eclipse plugin's compiler that does DSLD scripts compilation. I got some results by dynamically adding URL to sysetmClassLoader directly in DSLD script, but I wonder if there is some cleaner way to do that